# Photo printing API system?

Tags: api, printing, photo

I am looking for options to provide customers on my website a way to order prints for photos. (It is a photo sharing site, so it needs to be automated, I don't want any portfolio sites that require uploads and what not).

Basically it just needs where I send them the photos, the address, (and possibly billing info) and they make the prints and mail them out.

I have searched all over the place for such a system, but none seem to offer what I want.

I tried hacking snapfish (which worked, but it says "Return to Picasa" on the buttons, which makes it sort of lame...)

Any ideas?

Comment: No joy?  Looking for similar service.

Comment: All I have found so far is Digibug and Shutterfly, but neither really give me what I want.

Comment: Hello, just wanted to ask the same question about if you have found a service that does what you want. I am trying to set up a similar service for my site. It seems that snapfish works backwards - users need to register on snapfish and grant my site (app) access to their account and photos in the account. The photos that will be printed will already have been uploaded to my site so I dont want users to have to upload them to snapfish again, I would rather they just click a button that says Print on Snapfish which directs them to snapfish then I can send a list of urls which point to user pics.

Comment: FYI digibug shut down this service now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may already have found this by now but http://fotomoto.com seems to be a good fit for your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Peecho.com is up and coming. As of today, they are still trying to integrate with a photo printing supplier. Today they only provide printing of magazines, pdfs, and what not. I am eagerly waiting for them to provide standard photo prints. They call themselves the "print button for the internet".